# How to store numeric values in Zend_Config without loosing its type?

Tags: php, zend-framework, config

I decided to move some application settings from database to file system to be accessible via Zend_Config.
However I run in to one annoying thing, Zend_Config recognise all values as string ignoring data type.

Is there any magic way to parse config file keeping original types like float, integer, string and what would be best storage for it INI, XML, YAML or JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least not possible with [`Zend_Config_Xml`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.adapters.xml.html):

> Configuration data read into
>   Zend_Config_Xml are always returned as
>   strings. Conversion of data from
>   strings to other types is left to
>   developers to suit their particular
>   needs.

Not sure about the others. You can very much do something like

```
// config.php
return array('foo' => 1);

// bootstrap
$config = new Zend_Config(include 'config.php');
var_dump($config->foo); // int(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I also found that Json support it to.

Answer (score 1):

Zend will automagically turn integers, floats, and bools into their respective types with JSON and YAML. XML is always string, and INI has all the caveats and power of parse_ini_file() when it comes to choosing type.

If you want an explicit type, such as a particular object, you need to include that in the serialized data.

Comment: What part isn't working? You can force something to be recognized as a number by eg !!float 1.2 or !!int 42, and remember that y/n is True/False in YAML-land. (Though the full spec is pretty PHP-like in what is a bool.)

Comment: I mean in my case numbers are represented as strings, at least in default parser. And its weird as Zend_Config_Yaml understand only 2 type of values BOOLEAN and STRING, I have tried to apply your magic to my config file but it does not work.